# What ald stands for in CustomLog in Apache

Tags: apache, logging

I am having a problem where the error log is being filled but the access log is not filled. And I need to review the logs.
This is the configuration in apache2.conf
And I have tried to find what the ald stands for with no luck.

```
# Global error log.
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/system_error_log

LogLevel warn

LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" ald
LogFormat "\"%r\" %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" ssl

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sites_access_log ald
```

Is that what is making the access logs not to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ald` is a nickname for the first `LogFormat` shown, note it has `ald` specified after it. The `CustomLog` directive will now use that as instructions for what to log.

If you wanted, you could change it to something else, and as long as you changed the corresponding part in the `CustomLog` line, the results would be exactly the same.

Comment: So if nothing is wrong, sites_access_log should be filled with data, and in this case it isn't. Is 660 for sites_access_log a correct set of permissions?

Comment: So something is probably wrong, but your question specifically asked what `ald` is, which I've answered. This would not prevent your logs from writing, you have another problem somewhere.